# Are there polyominoes which tile half-plane but tile no strip with any width?

Tags: tiling, polyomino

In Golomb's hierarchy: If a polyomino tiles strip then tiles half-plane. (Ok, it's trivial.)
But what is with other direction? Is there an example which tiles half-plane but doesn't tile any strip?

Comment: As far as I am aware, no such polyominoes are known; see e.g. [Golomb's original paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82068433.pdf) or [Herman Tulleken's book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333296614_Polyominoes) for references to these problems that do not find any examples. Of course it will be hard to confidently assert a negative result here, but I would be quite surprised if you found any examples. Certainly the nonexistence of such polyominoes has not been shown, though.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

(Not a solution)
OP clarified that they want  "example **tile** which tiles half-plane but doesn't tile any strip".

This solution interprets the question as "example **tiling** which tiles half-plane but doesn't tile any strip".

---

Prove by induction that the $L-$polynomino consisting of 3 squares can perfectly tile a $2^n \times 2^n$ grid with 1 corner square removed such that every internal grid line intersects with a tile.

Use this to generate a tiling of the quarter-plane and reflect it to  get the half-plane, but there is no strip since the only grid line that doesn't intersect a tile is $ y = 0 $.

Comment: Did you mean $L$-polyomino? If so, which one there are many polyominoes with an L shape.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, autocorrect. I clarified which one it is.

Comment: But the L-polyomino can tile a strip if we use other tiling.
My question is. Is there polyomino which can tile half-plane, but no tiling exists with that polyomino which tiles any strip.

Comment: That polyomino doesn't satisfy the OP requirement of **not** tiling any strip

Comment: @MátéBelényesi Ah k. I took a different interpretation of the phrasing.